# Return value from function parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, nested, fingerprintjs2

I'm trying to use the [fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) javascript library, to get browser fingerprints.

The following code works ok:

```
new Fingerprint2().get(function (result) {
    var output = result;
    document.write(output);
});
```

However, I would like to set a variable outside of this block, to be used later e.g.:

```
var output;

new Fingerprint2().get(function (result) {
    output = result;
});

document.write(output);
```

but in this case I get the output:

```
undefined
```

I'm guessing this is related to scope, so is there any way to set the variable in the outer scope, or do I need to put all following code inside this function call?

I've read other questions about getting the value of nested functions, but none seem to work in this case.

Comment: "related to scope" - no, it is because you call `document.write(output);` before `output = result;` is executed

Comment: it's undefined because `document.write(output);` is called before your callback

Comment: The get call runs asynchronously so the `document.write(output)` is called while the `$.get()` call is still running.

Comment: Thanks for the info - so is it possible to use a library like this in a way which allows setting a global variable, or do I have to assume all subsequent code using the output needs to be inside this block, as shown in the first example?

Comment: JavaScript is an event-driven language and the way you are trying to design your code is outside the paradigm. You need to re-think your algorithm to conform to event-driven programming. A high-level way to look at it is as a chain of function calls. Any code that uses output should be called within your `$.get()` call. The code can be encapsulated in a separate function but due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX you need to follow the event-driven paradigm,

Comment: What you basically want is a synchronous call to `$.get()`.. Which has been deprecated recently :(

Comment: Yes, I think I was looking for a way to call the method synchronously, in a way that would allow me to continue with the rest of the code on the page. My main problem is that there is alot of other javascript on the page, and inside some of that, I need to use the fingerprint value, so I was hoping that I wouldn't have to move all that code inside this call.

Answer (score 0):

this will not work because you are printing the output before the asynchronous get has returned.

try this:

```
var output;

var callbackFunction = function(result) {
output = result;
document.write(output);
//do whatever you want to do with output inside this function or call another function inside this function. 
}

new Fingerprint2().get(function (result) {
   // you don't know when this will return because its async so you have to code what to do with the variable after it returns;
   callbackFunction(result);
});
```

Comment: This is similar to the first example I gave - where the document.write worked, but I'd like the output variable to be available in the outer scope, to be used by other functions if possible.

Comment: Well you can 't. The code is asyncronous so you will need to wrap it. What you can do is attach a call back function and inside that function do what ever you want to do outside the async block

Comment: @Arno_Geismar - so if I had another function `DoSomething(result)`, how can I use a callback to trigger that - to run afterwards, with the fingerprint result?

Answer (score 0):

it is not the way u should do it.
i"m writeing the code using ES6.

```
let Fingerprint2Obj = new Fingerprint2().get(function (result) {
    let obj = {
     output: result
    }
    return obj;
});
```

you can't call the var outside the function, instand if you send it out via object or string.
    document.write(Fingerprint2Obj.output);

Comment: hum I don't think `Fingerprint2Obj ` will take the value returned by the callback

Comment: this doesn't solve OP's problem of wanting a value returned from an asynchronous call in a global variable that can then be called.